# TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object: Cannot find where my data turned into "None Type"

Tags: python, typeerror

I **just** started to learn code, and I **just** started to learn python
I wanted to ask about something that I am practicing in jetbrains academy

when I code like below,
I get
**TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object**

I know that there has been couple of questions about this TypeError,
but I could not understand the comments,
and I couldn't figure out what's wrong....
Do some of you guys mind having a look at this and tell me why I get the error...?
And **please** comment more when there's something awkward

```
# declaring the current status of the coffee machine
def status(water, milk, beans, cups, money):
    print('The Coffee machine has:')
    print(water, 'of water')
    print(milk, 'of milk')
    print(beans, 'of coffee beans')
    print(cups, 'of disposable cups')
    print(money, 'of money')


# espresso
def espresso(water, beans, money):
    water -= 250
    beans -= 16
    money += 4
    return water, beans, money

# latte
def latte(water, milk, beans, money):
    water -= 350
    milk -= 75
    beans -= 20
    money += 7
    return water, milk, beans, money

# cappuccino
def cappuccino(water, milk, beans, money):
    water -= 200
    milk -= 100
    beans -= 12
    money += 6
    return water, milk, beans, money

# buy
def buying(water, milk, beans, money):
    coffee = input('What do you want to buy? 1 - espresso, 2 - latte, 3 - cappuccino: ')
    if coffee == 1:
        water, beans, money = espresso(water,beans, money)
        return water, milk, beans, money
    elif coffee == 2:
        water, milk, beans, money = latte(water, milk, beans, money)
        return water, milk, beans, money
    elif coffee == 3:
        water, milk, beans, money = cappuccino(water, milk, beans, money)
        return water, milk, beans, money

status(water, milk, beans, cups, money)
water, milk, beans, money = buying(water, milk, beans, money)
status(water, milk, beans, cups, money)
```

Comment: what input are you passing?

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert user input to int.

> coffee = int(input('What do you want to buy? 1 - espresso, 2 - latte,
> 3 - cappuccino: '))

Answer (score 0):

The `input()` function returns a string, while you are checking for an integer.

Do this -

```py
# buy
def buying(water, milk, beans, money):
    coffee = input('What do you want to buy? 1 - espresso, 2 - latte, 3 - cappuccino: ')
    # Convert string to integer
    # keep in mind it will throw ValueError if input was not an integer
    coffee = int(coffee)
```

You can also just change your if statement to

```py
# Notice the quotes
if coffee == '1':
```

Also, it would be a good idea to return at the end of the function. This way, you won't get `TypeError` even on incorrect input (Say, when user enters 4)

```py
def buying(water, milk, beans, money):
    coffee = input('What do you want to buy? 1 - espresso, 2 - latte, 3 - cappuccino: ')
    
    if coffee == '1':
        water, beans, money = espresso(water,beans, money)
    elif coffee == '2':
        water, milk, beans, money = latte(water, milk, beans, money)
    elif coffee == '3':
        water, milk, beans, money = cappuccino(water, milk, beans, money)

    return water, milk, beans, money
```